# C# работа с базой данных MySQL (подключение)

Tags: c#, mysql

Когда пытаюсь подключиться к базе данных - выводит ошибку. Когда я подключаюсь к базе данных из моего компьютера - все нормально, а когда к базе данных хостинга - ошибка:

> Вызвано исключение: "MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlException" в
>   MySql.Data.dll
>
> Дополнительные сведения: Authentication to host 'localhost' for user
>   'id835937_root' using method 'mysql_native_password' failed with
>   message: Access denied for user 'id835937_root'@'localhost' (using
>   password: YES)

Код:

```
string conStr = "SERVER=localhost;" + "DATABASE=!;" + "UID=!;" + "PASSWORD=!;";
using (MySqlConnection con = new MySqlConnection(conStr)) {
  try {
    string sql = "INSERT INTO `articles` (`article_title`, `article_text`) VALUES ('hi', 'hello');";
    MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(sql, con);
    con.Open();
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    MessageBox.Show("Данные добавлены!");
  } catch (Exception ex) {
    MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
  }
}
```

Comment: Почему это "SERVER=localhost" если должен быть хостинг?

Comment: На хостинге прямо написано "используйте в качестве сервера localhost"

Comment: Сюдя по `MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);` у вас программа запускается на компьютере и подсоединяется к БД, кот. на хостинге? Если да, то нужно указывать адрес сервера, а не локалхост.

Comment: @Bulson использую 000webhost. Там написано: хост - localhost, никакого адреса машины. Можете подсказать?

Comment: Не совсем понятна ситуация. Объясните, где запускается программа, а где установлена БД. Уточните.

Comment: "Используйте localhost как адрес хоста"

Comment: @Bulson БД установлена на хостинге 000webhost, запускаю на своем компьютере

Comment: Локалхост работает если у вас и программа и БД на одном и том же компе, а у вас не так. Нужен точный адрес сервера.

Comment: А Вы знаете как получить адрес сервера 000webhost?

Comment: Я не знаю такого хостера. Но должна быть панель администрирования или доступ по ssh, где можно узнать ip-адрес вашего сервера.

Comment: Я нашел эти сервера, но все равно выводит ошибку:
ns01.000webhost.com
ns02.000webhost.com

Comment: Вызвано исключение: "MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlException" в MySql.Data.dll

Дополнительные сведения: Unable to connect to any of the specified MySQL hosts.

Comment: сюдя по префиксу `ns` в названиях, это dns сервера хостера. Это не то, что вам надо. Зайдите в админ-панель, ищите там адрес своего сервера БД.

Comment: эту проблему нужно решать с помощью тех.поддержки хостера. Не все предоставляют внешние подключения к БД, а если и предоставляют, то настройки соединения разных хостеров различаются. Если у вас там размещен сайт, можете попробовать в качестве имени сервера использовать имя вашего сайта, но это просто предположение которое не обязано работать. Кроме того нужен номер порта сервера на котором MySQL слушает входящие запросы, если у него разрешено слушать внешние соединения.